# Resources for JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Hey I am new to java and wondering where to learn about JDBC, any help is appreciated. I have looked at oracles documentation but am still having difficulty with getting even a simple database to run. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same problem and used http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/. This helped me a lot. I was wondering what you were planning on using the database for. That would help me give you a better recommendation. However for your purposes, you may be better off with serialization.

Answer (score 1):

At least two sites just for jdbc tutorials :)

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/

http://www.jdbctutorial.net/

Similar post on SO

[Java and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite)

[JDBC Video Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991540/jdbc-video-tutorials)

[General JDBC Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612741/general-jdbc-setup)

Wiki book

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I used the [JDBC trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) when I need to write an ETL program and it helped me out quite a bit. That and the [Javadocs API's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).